# How to write to IBuffer?

Tags: javascript, uwp, buffer

I'm trying to write to `IBuffer` - here is my attempt (consider `buffer` is `IBuffer`):

```
const stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream()

const writer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(stream)

writer.byteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.littleEndian

writer.writeDouble(3.6) //for example

if (await stream.readAsync(buffer, await writer.storeAsync(), Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.none) !== buffer) throw 0
```

However it seems that the above code isn't properly copying over the stream for 2 reasons first it takes no time at all to execute the operation after `writer.storeAsync()`. second of all - I've a code that writes to 3dmf format using the above method to store the vertex and index data (since the API is only able to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.printing3d.printing3dmesh.createvertexpositions) and [query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.printing3d.printing3dmesh.getvertexpositions) an `IBuffer`) and it's failing with unspecified error when I try to store the models.

Comment: If you want write data with buffer, you need call [`DataWriter.WriteBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.writebuffer)method.